# crontab some commands works, others do not

Tags: python, macos, cron

**Summary**

I've got a python script that writes a row to a sqlite3 database. I would like to run it with crontab, but can't get it working.

**What I've tried so far**

```
crontab -l                
* * * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /Users/natemcintosh/dev/battery_condition/get_battery_condition.py 
* * * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /Users/natemcintosh/dev/battery_condition/testing_cron.py
```

The first command is the one that appends to the database row. I can copy and paste that command at the command line, run it, and it adds the row. It does *not* run every minute. The contents of `/Users/natemcintosh/dev/battery_condition/get_battery_condition.py` are

```py
# /Users/natemcintosh/dev/battery_condition/get_battery_condition.py
import subprocess
import re
import sqlite3
import datetime


def get_conds():
    # Run the command to get battery info
    command = "system_profiler SPPowerDataType".split()
    response = subprocess.run(command, check=True, capture_output=True)
    response = str(response.stdout)

    # Get just the parts of interest
    cycle_count = re.findall(r"Cycle Count: (\d+)", response)[0]
    condition = re.findall(r"Condition: (\w+)", response)[0]
    max_capacity = re.findall(r"Maximum Capacity: (\d+)", response)[0]
    now = str(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())

    return [now, cycle_count, condition, max_capacity]


def append_row_to_db(db_name: str, items: list):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
    with conn:
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO battery_condition VALUES (?,?,?,?)", items)
    conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the condition
    battery_condition = get_conds()

    # Append to the file
    filename = "/Users/natemcintosh/dev/battery_condition/battery_condition.db"
    append_row_to_db(filename, battery_condition)
```

The second command is a test script that does work.

```py
#/Users/natemcintosh/dev/battery_condition/testing_cron.py
import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("/Users/natemcintosh/Desktop/crontest.txt", "a+") as f:
        now = str(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())
        f.write(f"{now}\n")
```

Every minute, a new line appears in `/Users/natemcintosh/Desktop/crontest.txt` with the current date and time. I've also tried having the test script write to other locations on disk, and they all seem to work.

Comment: First, fix your shebangs! The first line of each script should be `#!` (not just `#`) followed by the path to the interpreter to run the script with (*not* the script itself); something like `#!/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`. That probably won't solve it, so the next thing to do is capture output & errors from the script by adding something like `>>/tmp/get_battery_condition.log 2>&1` to the command in crontab, and see what errors get reported. My guess is  something is missing from the environment under cron, but more info is needed to tell what.

Comment: Hi Gordon. You were indeed correct! Capturing the errors in a log showed that the `system_profiler` command was not found on the path when cron called it. Adding the full path to the executable fixed the issue! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson), I've figure out the issue. When I call `subprocess.run(command, check=True, capture_output=True)`, the command did not have the full path to the executable.

It used to be

```py
command = "system_profiler SPPowerDataType".split()
```

I got the full path to the `system_profiler` command with

```sh
$ which system_profiler
/usr/sbin/system_profiler
```

And fixed the line in my python script to be

```py
command = "/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPowerDataType".split()
```

The tool now runs successfully!